# Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на клавишу ws-серверу отправлялось одно сообщение, а при отпускании - другое?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, websocket

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на клавишу ws-серверу отправлялось одно сообщение, а при отпускании - другое?

Есть следующий код:

```
let ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.73:8001");

//посылаем серверу значения с клавиатуры
document.onkeypress = function(event) {
    ws.send(event.key);
}
```

Comment: Используйте `onkeydown`  и `onkeyup` вместо `onkeypress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделите событие `keypress` на `keydown` и `keyup`:

```js
//let ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.73:8001");

//посылаем серверу значения с клавиатуры
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    //ws.send('down' + event.key);
    console.log('down ' + event.key);
}

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
   // ws.send('up' + event.key);
    console.log('up ' + event.key);
}
```